# How to cache a docker image from a GitHub Action

Tags: java, docker, github-actions

I am having a scenario where I build an application using maven and docker on a GitHub workflow.

Then when the application (with docker image) is build, the integration testing of the application fails.

I often need to change existing integration tests without making changes in the application itself before rerunning The GitHub workflow. This causes the action to be build (and tested locally) with java and docker.

The build process is already done and a docker image uploaded to GitHub Packages. How can I check if this application already have a docker image?

Can I use actions/cache@v2 (https://github.com/actions/cache)? How? Docker is not mentioned in the languages it can cache...

Comment: Is your goal here to speed up the build process if there are no code changes?

Comment: yes... this is to speed up the build process. it is quite annoying to wait for maven build with junit tests when the build process has already performed this step...

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the [Docker's Build Push action](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action) for this purpose. Through the `build-push-action`, you can cache your container images by using the inline cache, registry cache or the experimental cache backend API:

### Inline cache

```yaml
name: Build and push
uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
with:
    context: .
    push: true
    tags: user/app:latest
    cache-from: type=registry,ref=user/app:latest
    cache-to: type=inline
```

Refer to the [Buildkit docs](https://github.com/moby/buildkit#inline-push-image-and-cache-together).

### Registry Cache

```yaml
name: Build and push
uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
with:
    context: .
    push: true
    tags: user/app:latest
    cache-from: type=registry,ref=user/app:buildcache
    cache-to: type=registry,ref=user/app:buildcache,mode=max
```

Refer to [Buildkit docs](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/tree/master#registry-push-image-and-cache-separately).

### Cache backend API

```yaml
name: Build and push
uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
with:
    context: .
    push: true
    tags: user/app:latest
    cache-from: type=gha
    cache-to: type=gha,mode=max
```

Refer to [Buildkit docs](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/tree/master#github-actions-cache-experimental).

I personally prefer using the Cache backend API as its easy to setup and provides a great boost in reducing the overall CI pipeline run duration.

You would not need to use the [cache action](https://github.com/actions/cache) since the above workflows intrinsically implements that and abstracts the workflow for us.

Here is an example: https://github.com/moja-global/FLINT.Reporting/blob/d7504909f8f101054e503a2993f4f70ca92c2577/.github/workflows/docker.yml#L54